# How to prove that a polynomial is monotonically increasing at x>2 where b is a constant in [-1,1]

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I prove that$$f(x) = 48b + 176x - 48bx + 45bx^4 - 51bx^5 - 15bx^6 + 21bx^7 + 3bx^8 - 3bx^9 + 80x^2 - 112x^3 - 45x^4 + 75x^5 + 25x^6 - 35x^7 - 2x^8 + 4x^9 - 112$$
is monotonically increasing at $x>2$. $f(x)$ can be factored as

$$f(x) = - (b(3x - 3) - 4x + 2)(x^8 + 10x^4 + 16) - (x - 1)(5x^4 - 3bx^4 + 16)(7x^2 + 2x - 5)$$

$b$ is a constant in $[-1,1]$

Comment: Have you tried taking the derivative?

Comment: Yes, the first derivative is $$f'(x)~=~160x - 48b + 180bx^3 - 255bx^4 - 90bx^5 + 147bx^6 + 24bx^7 - 27bx^8 - 336x^2 - 180x^3 + 375x^4 + 150x^5 - 245x^6 - 16x^7 + 36x^8 + 176
 $$

Comment: The first derivative has no roots

Comment: You write $x\gt 2$ in the title and $x\gt 4$ in the body. Which is correct?

Comment: corrected, sorry for that $x>2$.

Comment: Well that solves your problem! If the derivative is never zero, that means your function has no critical points and therefore has to be monotonous

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = 48b + 176x - 48bx + 45bx^4 - 51bx^5 - 15bx^6 + 21bx^7 + 3bx^8 - 3bx^9 + 80x^2 - 112x^3 - 45x^4 + 75x^5 + 25x^6 - 35x^7 - 2x^8 + 4x^9 - 112$$

We have
$f'(x)=-27 b x^8 + 24 b x^7 + 147 b x^6 - 90 b x^5 - 255 b x^4 + 180 b x^3 - 48 b + 36 x^8 - 16 x^7 - 245 x^6 + 150 x^5 + 375 x^4 - 180 x^3 - 336 x^2 + 160 x + 176$

$f''(x)=-2 (36 (3 b - 4) x^7 + (56 - 84 b) x^6 - 147 (3 b - 5) x^5 + 75 (3 b - 5) x^4 + 30 (17 b - 25) x^3 - 270 (b - 1) x^2 + 336 x - 80)$

$f^{(3)}(x)=-2 (252 (3 b - 4) x^6 + 6 (56 - 84 b) x^5 - 735 (3 b - 5) x^4 + 300 (3 b - 5) x^3 + 90 (17 b - 25) x^2 - 540 (b - 1) x + 336)$

$f^{(4)}(x)=-12 (252 (3 b - 4) x^5 + 5 (56 - 84 b) x^4 - 490 (3 b - 5) x^3 + 150 (3 b - 5) x^2 + 30 (17 b - 25) x - 90 (b - 1))$

$f^{(5)}(x)= -120 (126 (3 b - 4) x^4 - 56 (3 b - 2) x^3 - 147 (3 b - 5) x^2 + 30 (3 b - 5) x + 51 b - 75)$

$f^{(6)}(x)=-720 (84 (3 b - 4) x^3 - 28 (3 b - 2) x^2 - 49 (3 b - 5) x + 5 (3 b - 5))$

$f^{(7)}(x)= -5040 (3 b (36 x^2 - 8 x - 7) - 144 x^2 + 16 x + 35)$

$f^{(8)}(x)= -40320 (3 b (9 x - 1) - 36 x + 2)$

$f^{(9)}(x)=-362880 (3 b - 4)$

Now, since $-1\le b\le 1$, we have $f^{(9)}(x)=-362880 (3 b - 4)\gt 0$.

So, $f^{(8)}$ is monotonically increasing. With $f^{(8)}(2)=-40320 (51 b - 70)\gt 0$, we see that $f^{(8)}(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt 2$.

So, $f^{(7)}(x)$ is monotonically increasing for $x\gt 2$. With $f^{(7)}(2)= -5040 (363 b - 509)\gt 0$, we see that $f^{(7)}(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt 2$.

Similarly, since we have

$f^{(6)}(2)=-720 (1401 b - 1999)\gt 0$

$f^{(5)}(2)= -120 (3171 b - 4603)\gt 0$

$f^{(4)}(2)=-168 (603 b - 899)\gt 0$

$f^{(3)}(2)=-288 (64 b - 101)\gt 0$

$f''(2)=-144 (13 b - 23)\gt 0$

$f'(2)=0$

we see that $f'(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt 2$.

Comment: Thank you mathlove for the answer , Is it a must to check that all the higher derivatives are $>0$.

Comment: @johnmajimboni: In this method, yes. Since $f^{(9)}(x)\gt 0$, $f^{(8)}(x)$ is monotonically increasing. With $f^{(8)}(2)\gt 0$, we get $f^{(8)}(x)\gt 0$ for $x\gt 2$, so $f^{(7)}(x)$ is monotonically increasing... and so on.

Comment: @johnmajimboni: I added some explanations.

Comment: Thank you so much! Understood now.